# PHP decoding array

Tags: php, arrays

I've been trying to get tide information from the national weather service.  Here's the code that I've been playing with:

```
<?php

$homepage = file('http://opendap.co-ops.nos.noaa.gov/axis/webservices/highlowtidepred/response.jsp?stationId=8454000&beginDate=20150101&endDate=20151231&datum=MLLW&unit=0&timeZone=0&format=html&Submit=Submit');

$t2=explode("LST",$homepage[0]);
print_r($t2[1]);
echo "<br><br>";

$s =explode('item ',$t2[1]);
print_r($s[1]);
echo "<br><br>";

$u =explode("/time",$s[1]);
print_r($u);
echo "<br><br>";

$n=explode("<data>",$u[1]);
print_r($n);
echo "<br><br>";

$m=explode("<pred>",$n[0]);
print_r($m);
echo "<br><br>";

for($i = 0;$i<90;$i++)
{
   print_r ( $m[1][$i]);
   echo "<br>";
}


?>
```

and here's the output:

```
04:414.848H12:010.395L17:094.352H22:08-0.105L05:404.96H11:010.257L18:044.48H22:.......

date="01/01/2015">04:414.848H12:010.395L17:094.352H22:08-0.105L<

Array ( [0] => date="01/01/2015">04:41< [1] => >4.848H12:01< [2] => >0.395L17:09< [3] =>   >4.352H22:08< [4] => >-0.105L< )

Array ( [0] => >4.848H [1] => 12:01< )

Array ( [0] => > [1] => 4.848H )

4
.
8
4
8
<
/
p
r
e
d


>
<
 t
 y
 p
e
>
H
<
/
t
y
p
e
>
<
/
d
a
t
a
>
```

When I `print_r($m)` I get what I'm expecting but when I print out `$m[1][$i]` I get embedded text between `<>` describing the data element.  Is there an easy way to strip those out?  I've never seen this before and was wondering what to look under to read up on this.

Comment: There are a few spaces in the URL. It may or may not be relevant. If they should be there then replace them with `%20`.

Comment: The url contains a `format` (set to html at the moment) parameter... playing around with it briefly showed that it also supports xml, which is much easier to parse than html.

Comment: The spaces in the URL were just a typo.  I've removed them.  What I did find is:  filter_var($var, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); which strips out the tags.  I'll need to see how to strip out the special characters but that shouldn't be too hard.  As for changing the format, I tried that with both XML and CSV.  Doesn't seem to change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be easier to use their SOAP service to get the data that you are looking for.  At the very least, getting the data in XML format rather than from an HTML page is going to be far easier.  Here's an example of a SOAP call that will get you the same data as the HTML URL that you have in the question:

```
$wsdl = "http://opendap.co-ops.nos.noaa.gov/axis/webservices/highlowtidepred/wsdl/HighLowTidePred.wsdl";

$params = array("stationId" => "8454000", "beginDate" => "20150101", "endDate" => "20151231", "datum" => "MLLW", "unit" => 0, "timeZone" => 0);

$client = new SoapClient($wsdl);

$result = $client->__call("getHighLowTidePredictions", array("parameters" => $params));
```

$result should now be object type that was returned from the web service and will be FAR easier to iterate through than the HTML that you are currently working with.

Comment: There's a bunch of php errors in your answer, and after fixed I get 'object has no 'stationId' property'.

Comment: I couldn't edit your post, so I posted my fix as my own answer.

Comment: Bah, that's what I get for trying to re-type what worked for me in an interactive shell. :)  Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to use a proper parsing method, like regex, dom or even better a web service like what Mooseknuckles suggested.

```
$wsdl = "http://opendap.co-ops.nos.noaa.gov/axis/webservices/highlowtidepred/wsdl/HighLowTidePred.wsdl";
$params = array(
        "stationId" => "8454000",
        "beginDate" => "20150101",
        "endDate" => "20151231",
        "datum" => "MLLW",
        "unit" => 0,
        "timeZone" => 0
);
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl);
$result = $client->__call("getHighLowTidePredictions", array("parameters" => $params));

$records = $result->HighLowValues->item;

foreach($records as $record){
    $date = $record->date;
    foreach($record->data as $data){
        $time = $data->time;
        $pred = $data->pred;
        $type = $data->type;

        // do something with this data here
        // ...
    }
}
```